# Adding SSL to the Django app, Ubuntu 16+, DigitalOcean

Tags: django, ssl, digital-ocean

I am trying to add my SSL certificate to my django application according to this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z0L3u2Vn3Wo). I can turn on my website using 'https://ebluedesign.online'. But web browsers return something in style 'The certificate can not be verified due to a trusted certificate authority.' After accepting the messages, my page is displayed correctly.

My nginx file looks like this:

```
upstream app_server {
    server unix:/home/app/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    #listen 80;

    # add here the ip address of your server
    # or a domain pointing to that ip (like example.com or www.example.com)
    server_name ebluedesign.online;

    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate      /etc/letsencrypt/live/ebluedesign.online/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key   /etc/letsencrypt/live/ebluedesign.online/privkey.pem;

    keepalive_timeout 5;
    client_max_body_size 4G;

    access_log /home/app/logs/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /home/app/logs/nginx-error.log;

    location /static/ {
        alias /home/app/static/;
    }

    # checks for static file, if not found proxy to app
    location / {
        try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
    }

    location @proxy_to_app {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }
}
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name ebluedesign.online;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

My certificates are also visible here:

```
/etc/letsencrypt/live/ebluedesign.online/...
```

How can I solve this problem with SSL certificate. I use free SSL by https://letsencrypt.org/.

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: When you look at the warning, it says the certificate was issued for `www.korush.eu` - are you sure you got the right certificates in place?

Comment: It's interesting, I see something like that now (edit above). Maybe it will appear only after some time? EDIT: I had an error in the domain name. I corrected, I'm sorry for the trouble.

Comment: are you sure your letsencrypt certificate is not in trial/test mode?

Comment: It looks like a test certificate, can I easily turn it into a production one?

Comment: for me adding `root /path/to/your/static/directory;` in NGINX config fixed for me.

Answer (score 1):

What is odd is if you go to http://bluedesign.online/ it works fine even though your file makes it seem as if port 80 isn’t listened too at all. Do you happen to have two setup files in nginx? It is possible that the one you posted is not being used.

I’ve followed this tutorial many times with success. You could try using it from scratch if you have the opportunity: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04